# Services to let me use a remote PC (XP/Vista/Win7/Macintosh) (not my own) on a cost per hour basis?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, mac, services, remote-access

I want to test my software on Windows XP, but seeing as I only have Windows 7, it would be great to use a service to remotely use their PC.

Same goes with a Macintosh service for a different reason - I'd like to try out some software for about an hour. And I don't want to spend $1000 to do so. Hence it would be great if I could pay a tenner (or whatever) to play with a Mac remotely for an hour or two.

I should be able to install software and browse the internet on the intended platform.

Do any such services exist?

Comment: any reason you can't use a XP VM, least for the XP side of it? Windows 7 *does* have XP mode, and ms has time limited VMs available for browser testing

Comment: A point, but I would need to install the whole thing (and may even need an XP CD which I don't have). And even then, I can't be 100% sure it would act like a 'real' XP machine. So just to avoid hassle, it'd be great to use someone else's XP PC for 10 minutes.

Comment: you don't need a xp cd with either option, just MSVPC. Any remote use service *would* likely use virtualisation in *any* case